# How do I get the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex of ListView in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

As you know by question that what I want. I was using listbox. In `ListBox` we can get selected item by a simple line of code:
`listbox1.SelectedItem`. Now I am using `ListView`, how I get the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` of `ListView`.

Comment: Your question is so easy and it should not be asked in these kind of websites. You can do a search instead posting it here. `ListView.SelectedItems[0]`

Comment: @MahanGM you did not understand my question. i have asked that "how i get selected item?". i mean "When i clicked on some item (not mentioned already like you "[0]") it got selected. now how application knows that which item (by Index or other) is now Selected."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the answer that I found for my question:

```
urlList1.FocusedItem.Index
```

And I am getting selected item value by:

```
urlList1.Items(urlList1.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(0).Text
```

Comment: be careful, this can give you null exception when no item was selected.

Answer (score 12):

`ListView` returns collections of selected items and indices through the `SelectedItems` and `SelectedIndices` properties. Note that these collections are empty, if no item is currently selected (`lst.SelectedItems.Count = 0`). The first item that is selected is `lst.SelectedItems(0)`. The index of this item in the `Items` collection is `lst.SelectedIndices(0)`. So basically

```
lst.SelectedItems(0)
```

is the same as

```
lst.Items(lst.SelectedIndices(0))
```

You can also use check boxes. Set `CheckBoxes` to `True` for this. Through the `CheckedItems` and `CheckedIndices` properties you can see which items are checked.

Answer (score 9):

**VB6:**
`Listview1.selecteditem`

**VB10:**
`Listview1.FocusedItem.Text`

Comment: I want to point out that Excel VBA (2010 and possibly others) behave as VB6.

Comment: I've been trying to get the value of a ListView selection for a while and Listview1.FocusedItem.Text was the only thing that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub ListView1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Click
        Dim tt As String
        tt = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text
        TextBox1.Text = tt.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a heads-up, tt is already declared as a `string`, and the `.text` property of the `ListView` is of type `string`, so no need to add `.ToString`  on that last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView.FocusedItem.Index
```

or you can use foreach loop like this

```
int index= -1;
foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    if (itm.Selected)
    {
        index= itm.Index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the same item in a `listbox` using a `listview`, you can use:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    For aa As Integer = 0 To ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListView1.SelectedIndices(aa)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming the items in both line up the way you expect, at the same indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This for Getting column Index

```
Private Sub lvDetail_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lvDetail.MouseClick

    Dim info As ListViewHitTestInfo = lvDetail.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = lvDetail.FocusedItem.Index
    lvDetail.Items(rowIndex).Selected = True
    Dim xTxt = info.SubItem.Text
    For i = 0 To lvDetail.Columns.Count - 1
        If lvDetail.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(i).Text = xTxt Then
            MsgBox(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to consider providing code comments or otherwise expanding your answer to help the widest audience and encourage upvoting. ["Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)