# How to Loop through Listview items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, listview

I need some kind of loop, I think, to put into a variable for inclusion in access db. The problem I have at the minute is that with the code I am using, it gets the first value and if I click on another item, it retains the old value and dosen't update with new value.

How can I create a loop that will store the values from selected items. Thanks

```
           With lvSelectedItems.Items

                Dim username As String = .Item(0).Text
                Dim session As String = .Item(0).SubItems.Item(1).Text

                output = username + " : " + session
                MessageBox.Show(output)
            End With
```

Comment: This might be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693897/how-do-i-get-the-selecteditem-or-selectedindex-of-listview-in-vb-net

Comment: Nidzaaaa I know how to get selected items from listview, but how do I create a loop that gets all what I selected. The code I supplied just gets the first value. Thanks

Comment: But ?!? what is the problem with using `lvSelectedItems.Items.Count` for looping?

Comment: I even tried this, but is only showing 1 result. I need to get all listview items not the selected items. Thanks  msg = CStr(lvSelectedItems.Items.Count) If CDbl(msg) > 0 Then

            'With lvSelectedItems.Items

            For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectedItems.Items

                Dim username As String = lvSelectedItems.Items.Item(0).Text
                Dim session As String = lvSelectedItems.Items.Item(0).SubItems.Item(1).Text

                output = username + " : " + session

            Next
            MessageBox.Show(output)

            'End With

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`The code I supplied just gets the first value`  because you only looked at one item over and over:

```
 Dim username As String
 Dim session As String
 For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectedItems.Items 
      username = Item.Text 
      session = Item.SubItems.Item(1).Text
      output = username + " : " + session 

      console.WriteLine(output)        ' show results of this loop iteration
  Next
```

This will process all the items in `lvselecteditems` which is a very confusing name.  To process just the selected items use

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectedItems.SelectedItems
```