# ASP.Net C# How to find a control in Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to find a control in a selected row of a listview, can I do something like this:

```
lv_ListviewTest.Items(lv_ListviewTest.SelectedIndex).FindControl("ControlName")
```

What I had is:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            var ctrl = (HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("area");
            ctrl.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:LightSkyBlue; color:Black; padding:0px;";

        }
```

I can do it on Itemcommand, but I don't know how to trigger itemcommand when page re-load.

What I want to do is: when a button(not the button on the listview) clicked, the page reload and the focus will stop on the button of the listview.

Thank you very much.

Comment: in which event you want to find the control from listview

Comment: I hope it can be done on listview indexchanged

Answer (score 0):

you can find them below URL

[Find and access controls in EditItemTemplate of ASP.Net ListView](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Find-and-access-controls-in-EditItemTemplate-of-ASPNet-ListView.aspx)

[How to use ListView control in ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/44349-How-use-ListView-control-ASP.NET.aspx)

Comment: Actually I can do it on itemcommand, but I want to do it on indexchanged. Let me add some code in my question...

Answer (score 0):

In Button click Event of Outer Button add below code

```
 protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem  item in MyListView.Items)
                {

                    var ctrl = (HtmlContainerControl)item.FindControl("area");
                    ctrl.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:LightSkyBlue; color:Black; padding:0px;";


                }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't understand this: DropDownList innerDropdown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("innedDropedDOwnID"); and there is a compile error on row(I changed it to Item maybe because it's not DropDownList?) And I think there should be something like "If (MyListView.selected)"?

Comment: I have edit my code and I removed it..you can also removed it it will work

Comment: for getting selected item u can see it https://forums.asp.net/t/1738500.aspx?How+to+get+select+item+index+in+listview

Comment: Sorry, not understand about javascript, the setVal will always pop "1"?

Comment: please prefer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693897/how-do-i-get-the-selecteditem-or-selectedindex-of-listview-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found that I can use SelectedIndex and Session variable to store it:

When item selected:

```
protected void lv_ListviewTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["SelectedIndex"] = lv_ListviewTest.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

When the other button clicked:

```
protected void cmd_OtherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...............
        Button focusbutton = (Button)lv_ListviewTest.Items[Convert.ToInt16(Session["SelectedIndex"])].FindControl("MyControlLabel");
        focusbutton.Focus();
    }
```

So I can let my listview show what I selected before like ensurevisible do.