# VB.Net Delete data from Dictionary from SelectedValue in listbox

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm having trouble deleting data from my dictionary. I want whichever data is highlighted in the list box to be removed from the dictionary when the `Delete Library` button is clicked. After it is removed it will repopulate the list with the updated dictionary.

```
Public Class frmManager

    Dim Libraries As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub frmManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Libraries.Add("SVSU", "Zahnow Library")
        Libraries.Add("BR", "Fleschner Memorial Library")
        Libraries.Add("SDJ", "Scott D. James Technical Repository")

        populatelstLibrary()

    End Sub

    Sub populatelstLibrary()

        For Each library In Libraries
            lstLibraries.Items.Add(vbCrLf & library.Value & " --- " & library.Key)
        Next

     End Sub

    Private Sub btnDeleteLibrary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteLibrary.Click

        Dim key As String = ""

        If lstLibraries.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then

            For Each library In Libraries
                key = library.Key
                If lstLibraries.SelectedValue.Equals(key) Then
                    Libraries.Remove(key)
                End If
            Next

            lstLibraries.Items.Clear()
            populatelstLibrary()

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: For one thing, if `Libraries.Remove(lstLibraries.SelectedValue)` even compiles you must have `Option Strict Off`, so turn it `On` and fix the errors get that get flagged.

Comment: Did you even check whether the value of `SelectedValue` matched one of the keys in the `Dictionary`?  Based on your code, I don't see how it possibly could so it should be no surprise that nothing gets removed.

Comment: Also, what's the point of prepending a line break to each item in the `ListBox`?  It's not a `TextBox`.  Each item is displayed on it's own line anyway, so what purpose could that line break possibly serve?

Comment: You're right, the line break was pointless and is removed now. However, after turning `Option Strict On` I still do not get any errors.

Comment: How should I go about seeing if `SelectedValue` matches a key? Should I do a `for loop` through the dictionary and then an `if statement` inside the loop to check if equal to a key to remove it?

Comment: Have you even looked at the value of that `SelectedValue` property when you call `Remove`?  It should be quite obvious just from that that it doesn't match a key.  Look at how you're creating the items in the first place.  You're combining a key with a value and some additional text.  How can that combination possibly then match just a key?

Comment: *"However, after turning Option Strict On I still do not get any errors"*. I don't see how that's possible. `Remove` expects a `String` and you're passing an `Object` reference and `Option Strict On` won't allow that narrowing conversion to be done implicitly. I don't believe that you actually turned `Option Strict On`. If you did then your system is broken.

Comment: I can guarantee you I turned it on. `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults > Option Strict On & Option Explicit On` Still 0 errors.

Comment: In that case, you didn't turn it `On` for the current project. What you did is a good thing because it will now be `On` by default for future projects but it has no effect on existing projects. You need to set it in the project properties for an existing project.

Comment: One thing to note: make sure you have it clear in your mind the difference between a "key" and a "value". A "value" won't ever match a "key".

Comment: Have a look though this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693897/how-do-i-get-the-selecteditem-or-selectedindex-of-listview-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are populating your listbox with BOTH Key and Value and also the string "---" therefore the contents of the listbox  will NEVER match either KEY or VALUE but it will match BOTH together and only with the same string "---".

So when you test for equality, test for the same equality you used to load the list.

The code below works, but probably could be streamlined more.
The important thing is not that it works, 
but that it works and you UNDERSTAND where you were going wrong, and why too.

```
'
Dim key As String = ""
Dim tmpLibraries As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

If lstLibraries.SelectedIndex > -1 Then

  For Each Item In Libraries
    If lstLibraries.SelectedItem.Equals(Item.Value & " --- " & Item.Key) Then
      'this will be dropped
    Else
      tmpLibraries.Add(Item.Value, Item.Key)
    End If
  Next

  lstLibraries.Items.Clear()
  Libraries = tmpLibraries
  tmpLibraries = Nothing
  PopulatelstLibraries()

End If
'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `'this will be dropped`

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, so if it equals the selected item's string then it is not added to temp library, thus not being included to the main `Libraries` when updated to repopulate. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Glad to be able to help as we all started out the same, as beginners :) and we never stop learning

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to remove an item by key based on the selection then the selection needs to provide that key.  The logical way to do that is by binding, e.g.

```
With lstLibraries
    .DisplayMember = "Text"
    .ValueMember = "Key"
    .DataSource = Libraries.Select(Function(kvp) New With {.Key = kvp.Key, .Text = $"{kvp.Value} --- {kvp.Key}"}.ToArray()
End With
```

After that, the `SelectedValue` actually will be one of the keys from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ValueMember if you want to use SelectedValue. You need to bind Libraries to lstLibraries with a BindingSource as the DataSource. Then you can Remove from the Libraries with the .Key which is now the SelectedValue. After the Remove call your populatelstLibraries again to keep the ListBox synced with the Dictionary.

```
Dim Libraries As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Libraries.Add("SVSU", "Zahnow Library --- SVSU")
    Libraries.Add("BR", "Fleschner Memorial Library --- BR")
    Libraries.Add("SDJ", "Scott D. James Technical Repository --- SDJ")
    populatelstLibrary()
End Sub

Sub populatelstLibrary()
    ListBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource(Libraries, Nothing)
    ListBox2.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ListBox2.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Libraries.Remove(CType(ListBox2.SelectedValue, String))
    populatelstLibrary()
End Sub
```