# When i filter and select a filter row in listview and input some value, in listview is correct but in excel appears in first line

Tags: excel, vba, listview, filter

When i filter and select a filtered row in listview and input some value with button, in listview is correct but in excel appears in first line out of filter.

First Screenshot - value test in "Unidade"-"Taquari"
[image]

Second Screenshot - value test in first row "Uberaba"
[image]

**RISCOS = ListView**

**PosiçãoAtual = My selected row**

```
Sheets("Gerenciamento de Riscos Tableau").Select


Riscos.SetFocus


Dim PosiçãoAtual As Variant
    PosiçãoAtual = Riscos.SelectedItem.Index + 1


    Cells(PosiçãoAtual, 2).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Cells(PosiçãoAtual, 6).Value = TextBox4.Text
    Cells(PosiçãoAtual, 7).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Cells(PosiçãoAtual, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text


     With Riscos


        .SelectedItem.SubItems(1) = TextBox1.Text
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(5) = TextBox4.Text
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(6) = TextBox3.Text
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(7) = TextBox5.Text


    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that *"Help-me, is very important for me."* is not a question. You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and [ask]. Screenshots might help to explain your issue better. • What is `Riscos`?

Comment: Riscos is a ListView.

Comment: In addition to what @Pᴇʜ said re: screenshots, please read [why we should avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). What's PosiçãoAtual? Showing relevant code will also help to understand the issue

Comment: added the screenshot, sorry

Comment: What are the red arrows in your screen trying to show?

Comment: I put values ​​in a filtered row "Taquari" but returned me in the first row "Uberaba"

Comment: i need to click on the filtered Row and edit the value of that

Comment: There is no such property as `ListView.SelectedItem.Index`. Use `ListView.SelectedIndex` or `ListView.SelectedItems ` instead. Both are `Collection` type. I assume you do not use `Option Explicit` either. That may be the reason for always getting 1 for `PosiçãoAtual`. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693897/how-do-i-get-the-selecteditem-or-selectedindex-of-listview-in-vb-net

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, when i use SelectedIndex or SelectedItems return : compile error method or data member not found